# Importing excel file columns into python script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

Right now I have a script that is designed to send Whatsapp messages. It takes phone numbers `names = ['phone number 1', 'phone number 2', 'phone number 3']` and uses that to find the contacts in Whatsapp.

I want to instead be able to fill out the "names" field with an excel document.

I am in python 3.8.3 , and have installed pandas already.

I have tried to create small test script to test everything and have not been successful.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('contactsList.xlsx')

print(df)
```

The "contactList.xlsx" is located in the same folder as the script I am trying to run.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/csvHelps.py", line 3, in 
> df = pd.read_excel('contactsList.xlsx')
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
> io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in **init**
> self._reader = self._enginesengine
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in **init**
> import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
> File "/Users/zafarb/PycharmProjects/CelebrateMercy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 110, in import_optional_dependency
> raise ImportError(msg) from None
> ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.

Heres is the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error you are missing a dependency,

`Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.`

Run `pip install xlrd`

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the issue
Thank you so much - this worked.

I have a new question though. My new output becomes
```
0    'phone number 1'
1    'phone number 2'
```
Is there a way that I can get rid of the 0 and 1, so that way the only thing being read are the two phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

xlrd is a library for reading data and formatting information from Excel files, whether they are .xls or .xlsx files.

It needs to be installed, in your preferred terminal run

pip install xlrd

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked.

I have a new question though. My new output becomes
```
0    'phone number 1'
1    'phone number 2'
```
Is there a way that I can get rid of the 0 and 1, so that way the only thing being read are the two phone numbers?